# ScrollView containing TextView does not scroll

Tags: java, android

I have a textview displaying many individual words, each word is a link using Spans and setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  The textview is wrapped by a ScrollView.

However the ScrollView does not work as the links in the TextView are activated instead.

Is there a way to combine a ScrollView and TextView so that both the scrolling and links in the text work?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the links or the TextView are consuming the touches. A starting point might be to play around with the [onTouch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) of the views involved to find out where the touches are consumed and then passing those touches to the ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks. A good idea, I will have a play around with onTouch() and see what I can find out.

Comment: I have now changed tack and will allow the user to switch between scroll and click mode using a floating button.